# WDM driver develop, sc start error

Tags: driver, windows-kernel, wdm

I'm learning developing drivers with win10 1709 and visual studio 2017. I created a empty wdm project and build it into mydriver1.sys

But I can't start service

sc create mydriver binpath= mydriver1.sys type= kernel
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

sc start mydriver
[SC] StartService FAILED 2:

Then I checked the mydriver1.sys with Dependency Walker, it shows that many sys files and dll are missing.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdNuw.jpg)

How shall I solve is Problem. I don't think downloading those dlls one by one is a good idea.

My Code is a simple Hello world:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

VOID Unload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
   KdPrint(("Good bye Driver\n"));
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING     RegistryPath)
{
   KdPrint(("Hello Driver\n"));
   DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;

   return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: at first nothing missing. you wrong interpret Dependency Walker screen. you import only from *ntoskrnl.exe*. at second wdm driver ( `/DRIVER:WDM` exist in *link.exe* command line `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_WDM_DRIVER` in `DllCharacteristics`) at all can not be loaded via `sc start mydriver`. wdm driver mandatory must have `AddDevice` registered - you have not. you write simply legacy driver. remove wdm option

Comment: but faster af all (based on error code) you simply not register or wrong register driver